# Italic question's statement and the reason of an error

Tags: environments, exam, code, italic

Here is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  


\begin{document}



    \newgeometry{top=1.5in,hmargin=1in, bottom = 2 in} 
    
    \pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
 Assignment 1 \\

%\vspace{2\baselineskip}

\hspace{10pt}

% Author names and affiliations
\large
Josef,  \\


Sept. 13, 2021.
\end{center}
\date{September 2021}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{question}
$\quad$

\lipsum[1]

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

But I need the statement of my question to be italic, could someone help me in adjusting my code to make this, please?

**EDIT:**
Also, I have the following error
[image]

Could anyone help me correct it please?

Comment: the error is because the exam class you are using already has a question environment but then you try to define it again with `\newtheorem`

Comment: do you really want theorem constructs like Corollary defined in an exam ?

Comment: No I do not @DavidCarlisle I just always(if I do not have enough time) take the beginning of my code in every document I start which is not the most efficient way to do things

Comment: But it did not write the word "question" and I want it to be written before each question @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Always start from an empty preamble and only add packages or definitions that you _need_  If you just copy random commands from previous documents then you are almost certain to get errors like this with clashing multiple definitions.

Comment: What about my last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **Question** and its text in italics. I maintained the packages to check for loading incompatibilities with the `exam` class.

The `\qformat{...}` command and `\renewcommand{\questionshook}{...}` gives you control of the style of the question.

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
%%%\newtheorem{question}{Question} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
    \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
\def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
        \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \if@mainmatter
                \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
                \fi
                \fi
                ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
        \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
                \thesection. \ %
                \fi
                ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions


\qformat{\normalfont \bfseries Question \thequestion \hfill}% added<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\itshape}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.5in,hmargin=1in, bottom = 2 in} 

\thispagestyle{empty}

        \begin{center}
        \Large
            Assignment 1 \\         
            %\vspace{2\baselineskip}            
            \hspace{10pt}           
            % Author names and affiliations
            \large
            Josef,  \\ \bigskip
                        
            \today  
    \end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

    \begin{questions}
    \question
        \lipsum[1]
    \question
        How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
        wood?
    \question Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```